# Wordpress navigation menu creation when theme enabled

Tags: wordpress, wordpress-theming

I need to create a navigation menu in wordpress when i activate my theme.

I have some pages created at the time of theme activation and i need to add these pages to the  navigation menu .

I had created the menus using `register_nav_menu` , but i cant add the pages under this menu .

Please help me
Regards

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried the wp_update_nav_menu_item() function?

```
wp_update_nav_menu_item(
    $id_of_menu, 
    0, /* Use 0 to create a new menu item */
    array(
        'menu-item-title'   => 'Title',
        'menu-item-classes' => 'title',
        'menu_item_url'     => 'url',
        'menu_item_status'  => 'published')
);
```

That should do the trick for you! Have a look at http://www.acousticwebdesign.net/wordpress/how-to-create-wordpress-3-navigation-menus-in-your-theme-or-plugin-code/ for more in depth info.

Answer (score 1):

Just write in your functions.php
// To add Orders as main menu after dasboard.

http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/add_dashboard_page

```
function dasboard_sub_menu() {  
    global $menu; 
    global $submenu; 
    $menu[6] = array( __('Orders'), 'read', 'edit.php?post_type=shop_order', '', 'menu-top menu-top-first menu-icon-orders', 'menu-dashboard', 'none' );
    $menu[7] = array( __('Catalogue'), 'read', 'edit.php?post_type=product', '', 'menu-top menu-top-first menu-icon-catalogue', 'menu-dashboard', 'none' );
    $menu[8] = array( __('Coupons'), 'read', 'edit.php?post_type=shop_coupon', '', 'menu-top menu-top-first menu-icon-coupon', 'menu-dashboard', 'none' );
   //$menu[4] = array( '', 'read', 'separator1', '', 'wp-menu-separator' );
    $menu[59] = array( '', 'read', 'separator2', '', 'wp-menu-separator1' );
    $menu[99] = array( '', 'read', 'separator3', '', 'wp-menu-separator2' );
    $menu[56] = array( '', 'read', 'separator4', '', 'wp-menu-separator3' );
    $menu[57] = array( '', 'read', 'separator5', '', 'wp-menu-separator4' );
    $submenu[ 'index.php' ][1] = array( __('Reports'), 'read', 'admin.php?page=woocommerce_reports' );
}  
add_action( 'admin_menu', 'dasboard_sub_menu' );  
// To add Submenu Orders under Dashboard Sub Menu
// To add Orders as main menu after dasboard
```